# Wordpress - CPT, ACF - How to customize admin edit-post page?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, advanced-custom-fields

I want to edit/customize the admin edit-post page.

### Description

- I've made a Custom Post Type
- Made two groups of Advance Custom Fields groups, `group_1` and `group_2` (each include several custom fields)
- Made two custom user role types `user_type_1` and `user_type_2`

### The goal

- I want `user_type_1` to be able to write `group_1` and only read `group_2`.
- I want `user_type_2` to be able to write `group_2` and only read `group_1`.

### The Question

- How can I edit the admin edit-post page? **(What actions to call to manipulate them?)**
- What actions to delete default body in element `id="post-body-content"`
- Custom render the ACF body in element `id="postbox-container-2"`

Answer (score 0):

I'll be building a jQuery script that will set the input fields to read-only with `$('input').attr('readonly', true);` (simplified) Based on the current users role.

I was afraid, when I won't make this a field, it won't save the grayed out fields back to the DB.

This is the complete code I anyone would need this in the future:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'rtt_conditional_acf_post_input');

function rtt_conditional_acf_post_input()
{

    $role = rtt_get_current_user_roles();

    $target = null;
    if (in_array("user_type_1", $role)) {
        $target = '#acf-group_5e1d936b7e583'; // <--- element id of group_1

    } else if (in_array("user_type_2", $role)) {
        $target = '#acf-group_5e1d93bdf2a56'; // <--- element id of group_2
    }


    if($target) {
        ?>

        <script type="application/javascript">

            $ = jQuery;
            $(document).ready(function () {

                let target = '<?php echo $target; ?>';

                $(target).find("input").each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('readonly', true);
                });

            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }
}

function rtt_get_current_user_roles()
{
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        $user = wp_get_current_user();
        $roles = ( array )$user->roles;
        return $roles; // This returns an array
        // Use this to return a single value
        // return $roles[0];
    } else {
        return array();
    }
}
```

I'm only going to add a check if current page is post-edit before executing the complete script.